# Patch from Pure Data sounding different loaded in libpd(android)

Tags: android, puredata, libpd

I have done a patch in Pure Data for a metronome app I am working on.
The patch (a click) sounds good in Pure Data, but when I load it into 
my app (built with libpd and Android Studio) there are some slight 
variations in the dynamics of the sound.

Does the Android system have any compression or something that change 
the output in speakers over time??

The sound (wav) I use is normalized and it sounds even when played in Pure
Data editor.

Grateful for any input that can help me solve this strange behaviour.

Comment: Sp what is the system you developed your patch on? E.g. OSX is known to have a compressor.

Comment: @umläute - I am using Pure Data on Ubuntu(linux), and running patch on this sounds good. It is when the patch is running on my phone that there is small changes in the sound. Its strange because the sound is a single wav loaded in an tabread and then played by a metro.

Comment: you might want to add this information to the question itself (rather than hide it away in a comment); also: what is the audio backend you are using? alsa, jack, portaudio/pulseaudio?

Comment: @umläute - How does the audio backend on my computer affecting the android phones sound system? Its on the phone the sound is behaving odd not on the computer. Sorry but I dont understand what you are after....

Comment: your question does not indicate whether the problem really is on the phone side - it could as well be your development system that does *something* to the sound which you are then expecting on the phone.

Comment: @umläute - the patch in Pure Data is repeating the same sound (wav file in tabplay) so the source of sound should be the same all time, so if my Ubuntu system is changing something, the patch played in Pure Data editor (in Ubuntu) should not sound with even sound (even sound = good), or?

However when I play the same patch from my app on my android phone the sound is NOT even (bad!), so I came up with the conclusion that there is something on my phone doing something with the sound. Therefore I asked my initial question.

Maybe there is a flaw in my conclusion.....

Comment: probably only the question is flawed so try to refine it; also it is very easy to lower the volume to see i this is the problem.